# Angular2 + Apache Cordova VS2017

Tags: android, cordova, angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I'm in the process of hopefully getting Angular 4 working within Apache Cordova without a reliance on Ionic framework, and I am having some success. When running the app as a website it all works ok, and Angular displays a 'hello world' message, however when moving the app to an Android emulator I receive the following error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Map is not defined'.

From my limited understanding this is due to a lack of ES6 support within the Android javascript engine, which I can resolve through the use of ES6 shims. I have added es6-shim to my webpack.config, and I can confirm that the contents of es6-shim is being output into the resultant .js file (vendor.js), however I am still seeing the error message thrown by vendor.js when I run the app.

I tried to isolate where the error occurs by importing the es6-shim.js directly in the index.html, which actually seems to resolve the issue (a different error is thrown by vendor.js: 'WeakMap is not defined', which I am aware is due to the fact that es6-shim doesn't contain a WeakMap implementation.

Is there something about my implementation that means that compiling es6-shim into the webpack compiled vendor.js is causing Cordova to throw an error when loading said javascript file? I also tried breaking out the polyfills within webpack into a separate .js file, which I loaded in index.html prior to vendor.js, but the same error persisted.

Here is my webpack.vendor.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: [
                'es6-shim',
                'es6-weak-map',
                '@angular/core',
                '@angular/common',
                '@angular/compiler',
                '@angular/http',
                '@angular/platform-browser',
                '@angular/platform-browser/animations',
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                '@angular/router',
                '@angular/forms',
                '@angular/animations',
                '@angular/animations/browser',
                'reflect-metadata',
                'bootstrap',
                'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
                'event-source-polyfill',
                'jquery',
                'zone.js'
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './www/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: 'css-loader' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'www', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        ] : [
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
            ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
```

and here is my tsconfig.json incase it helps:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
        "types": [ "node" ],
        "outDir": "www"
    },
    "exclude": [ "platforms", "node_modules", "bower_components", "plugins", "merges", "res", "bin", "bld" ]
}
}
```